# 2^n vs (logn)! for large integer n

Tags: big-o

Okay, so I have a project about big-O notations to do, and it asks me to check which is bigger.

I have checked that (logn)! gets approximation as n^log(logn) by Sterling's approximation.
And I tried to check the limit value like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kdgU.png)

and got the result that 2^n is smaller than (logn)! for large enough numbers.
But i can't get confident about this, since for about 1000, 2^1000 is much much bigger than (log10)!.
Is this right or am I missing something?

Sorry that i am not used to ask here. 
Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Sterling's expansion states that `log x! ~ x log x - x + O(log x)`. So while `O(log (log n)!) = O(log n log log n)`, this does **not** mean that `O((log n)!) = O(n ^ (log log n))`, since trailing terms in the expansion translate to multiplicative factors. Taking logarithms of both sides gives `O(n)` vs `O(log n log log n)`, which means `O(2^n)` is asymptotically greater.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I thought it wrong. Now I understand.